# how to get compare time values and difference in python

Tags: python, datetime

i have 3 character type columns in my table has time format values i.e

while processing (in python 3.7) to in if condition i am using following statement;

```
t1 = '09:12' 
t2 = '09:10'
t3 = '20:00'

if datetime.strptime(t1, '%H:%M') > datetime.strptime(t2, '%H:%M'):
    print((datetime.strptime(t1, '%H:%M') - datetime.strptime(t2, '%H:%M')))
    # above prints 00:02 but i need it to be 00:12 but below statement raise error
    print((datetime.strptime(t1, '%H:%M') - datetime.strptime(t2, '%H:%M'))) + datetime.strptime(t2, '%M')
```

i need to ask

a) am i doing right thing to get compare above time values (string to date) or i have to compare it with strings values

b) i require difference of above subtract value with 00:12, please assist.

Comment: Can you explain further what you are trying to do? If these are times the difference is 2 minutes?

Comment: the difference between 9:10h and 9:12h is two minutes, why should it print 12?

Comment: @MrFuppes it is going to calculate grace (i.e10min) and late i.e2 min (it actually make 12 min)

Answer (score 3):

what about flooring t2's minute?

```
from datetime import datetime

t1 = '09:12' 
t2 = '09:10'

if datetime.strptime(t1, '%H:%M') > datetime.strptime(t2, '%H:%M'):
    print(datetime.strptime(t1, '%H:%M') - datetime.strptime(t2, '%H:%M').replace(minute=0))
    
# 0:12:00
```

Comment: thanks for reply it works as above but raise error 'AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'replace'' when i use it in variable    pl = ((datetime.strptime(t1, '%H:%M') - datetime.strptime(t2, '%H:%M')).replace(minute=0))

Comment: @aqbMh: yup, if you subtract a datetime object from another, you get a [timedelta object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) - which has no `replace` method (only datetime object).

Comment: @aqbMh: [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) aren't too bad either ;-)